# Cannot get Bash script to exit without executing unwanted commands

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script that works unless you tell it not to end the process. I have been banging my head against the wall trying to get this script to exit 0 without executing any other commands.

```
 #!/bin/bash

    createProcfile() {

    ps -eLf | grep -f process.tmp | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2,$10}' | sort -u | egrep -o '[0-9]{4,}' > pid.tmp

    }

 #  PIDproc=$(createProcfile)
    PIDFile=pid.tmp

    echo "Enter a process name"
    read process
    echo $process > process.tmp

    node_process_id=$(pidof $process)
    if [[ -z $node_process_id ]]; then
            echo "Please enter a valid process."
        rm process.tmp
        exit 0
    fi

    ps -eLf | grep $process | awk '{print $2,$10}' | sort -u | grep -v 'grep'
    echo "Would you like to kill this process(es)? (y/n)"
    read $answer

    if [[ $answer == n ]]; then
        exit 0
    else
        createProcfile
        kill -SIGKILL $(<"$PIDFile")
        rm $PIDFile
        createProcfile

        node_process_id=$(pidof $process)
        if [[ -z $node_process_id ]]; then
                echo "Process terminated successfully."
            rm process.tmp
            exit 0
        else
            echo "Process not terminated. Kill process manually."
            ps -eLf | grep $process | awk '{print $2,$10}' | sort -u | grep -v 'grep'
            rm $PIDFile
            rm process.tmp
            exit 0
        fi
    fi
```

I need it to exit without executing commands if I enter `n`. Right now, it kills the process(es) anyway.

Comment: for debugging such issues, paste your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix all the errors seen. Doing this could have saved your time!

Comment: Thank you, @Inian, I posted my edited script after running it through shellcheck.net. I can kill most processes, except for rsync, which I will have to kill manually. Any ideas on how to get it to kill all of those? Do I need to always get the parent PID and only kill that one?

Comment: @Inian shellcheck.net recommends to use `pgrep` instead of `grep` to get process IDs. However, with `pgrep`, I have to enter an exact process name. But with `ps -eLf | grep -f process.tmp | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2,$10}' | sort -u | egrep -o '[0-9]{4,}'`, I can enter partial names because of how `grep` works. Do you know of a way to use `pgrep` to accept partial process ID names?

Comment: Don't modify your question to ask about a different topic. Start a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` takes the *name* of a variable as the argument:

```
read answer
```

What you wrote is syntactically correct; `bash` would expand the current value of `answer` to get the name of the variable that `read` will set. Most likely, `answer` does not already have a value, so the command reduces to `read`, with no argument, in which case `read` sets the value of the parameter `REPLY`.

Note that if you were following the good practice of quoting all of your parameter expansions, you might have written `read "$answer"`, which expands to `read ""`, which would have produced an error indicating that `""` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: Nice catch! Exactly what was causing the issue.

Comment: The weird thing is that I changed `if [[ $answer == n ]]` to `if [[ $answer -eq "n" ]]` without changing `read $answer` to `read answer`, and the script exited as it was supposed to. But, that is definitely something I should have caught. Thank you!

Comment: `[[ $answer -eq "n" ]]` treats both the value of `$answer` and `n` as the names of variables with integer values. This expansion happens recursively (if `$answer == foo`, then `foo` is treated as the name of a variable to expand as well), until you reach either an undefined variable name (which is then treated as being equal to 0) or an actual integer, at which point integer comparison occurs.`[[ $answer -eq "n" ]]` likely ends up being evaluated as `[[ 0 -eq 0 ]]`, which obviously succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning answer wrong

```
read $answer
```

should be

```
read answer
```

Comment: Thank you. I am such a beginner.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it!

I changed:

`if [[ $answer == n ]]`

to:

`if [[ $answer -eq "n" ]]`

And, it worked!

Yes, after answering my own question, I found a lot more work to do, so...

Comment: I also changed it to `read answer` instead of `read $answer` as @SaintHax and @chepner pointed out.

Comment: It would also "work" if you used `if [[ $answer -eq y ]]`.

Comment: Yes, that does work @chepner. I used shellcheck.net to edit more errors. I cannot seem to get rsync, ssh, or scp to quit as they are connected to a remote server. But, when I execute `sudo kill -SIGKILL 5700`, for example, it will kill the process. I edited my original question with the new script. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use -eq for non-mathematical tests.  It's not portable, and you never know when something open source may decide to get in line with the rest of bourne shells.  Besides, it's a bad habit-- if you ever get a job writing ksh you'll wish you had not started that habit.

Comment: @SaintHax I changed it back to `==` already. It works when there is 1 PID for a process I input. However, when attempting to kill multiple PIDs from a file, it won't let me. So, if you can help with that, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: @Debug255 you've already selected an answer for this question, don't start a new one.  I'd start putting some echo's in and debug this one section at a time.  You've bitten off more than you can chew like this.